# Exercise 28, Article III, Schanuel and Lawvere's "Conceptual Mathematics" (2nd Edition).

Tags: category-theory

**Exercise 28**

If $X^{\circlearrowleft \alpha}$ is any object of $S^\circlearrowleft$ for which there exists an *injective* $S^\circlearrowleft$-map $f$ to some $Y^{\circlearrowleft \beta}$ where $\beta$ is in the subcategory of *automorphisms*, then $\alpha$ itself must be injective.

**Notation and Definitions**

- $S$ is the category of sets, with functions as morphisms ($S$-maps).
- $X^{\circlearrowleft \alpha}$ denotes a set $X$ equipped with an endomap $\alpha$.
- $S^\circlearrowleft$ is the category of endomaps of sets. An $S^\circlearrowleft$-map between objects $X^{\circlearrowleft \alpha}$ and $Y^{\circlearrowleft \beta}$ is an $S$-map $X \xrightarrow{f} Y$ which satisfies the equation $f \circ \alpha = \beta \circ f$.
- A map $X \xrightarrow{a} Y$ is **injective** iff for any maps $T \xrightarrow{x_1} X$ and $T \xrightarrow{x2} X$ (in the same category) if $a \circ x_1=a \circ x_2$ then $x_1=x_2$.

**Partial Solution**

If $T \xrightarrow{x_1} X$ and $T \xrightarrow{x2} X$ are $S$-maps such that $\alpha \circ x_1 = \alpha \circ x_2$, then $f \circ \alpha \circ x_1 = f \circ \alpha \circ x_2$. Since $f$ is an $S^\circlearrowleft$-map, $\beta \circ f \circ x_1 = \beta \circ f \circ x_2$. Composing boths sides with $\beta^{-1}$ ($\beta$ is an automorfism), we get $f \circ x_1 = f \circ x_2$.

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ were not only $S$-maps, but also $S^\circlearrowleft$-maps (for a given endomap $\tau$ on $T$), by the injectivity of $f$, we'd get $x_1=x_2$. However, this may not be the case. Therefore, **my question is**: how do I generalize this conclusion to all pairs of $S$-maps? I haven't found a way to do so, nor have I found any counterexamples. Should the statement of the problem be understood as making the stronger assumption that $f$ is injective as an $S$-map (in which case the previous proof suffices)?

Comment: One thing you can also do is replace $T$ by a set $T'$ endowed with an endomap and $x_1,x_2$ by maps $x'_1,x'_2$ that commute with the given endomap. There's a "canonical" way to do this, and in fact it allows you to also prove that $f$ is also injective as a map between sets.

Comment: Thanks! This is more or less what I did in my partial solution; however, I got stuck in the second part. Does this result you describe rely on the fact that beta is an automorphism? Or is it in general true that injective maps of endomaps are also injective maps of sets? The latter is not a priori obvious to me, since in general there are “less” maps of endomaps arriving at a given object than there are maps of sets. On the other hand, maps of endomaps “preserve more structure” than maps of sets. Therefore it is not clear (to me) which kind of injectivity, if any, is a stronger requirement.

Comment: While there are fewer maps of endomaps than there are between their domains, we can still recover all maps between two S-objects by constructing “free” endomaps on them and considering the maps of endomaps between those. So while you are right that there are fewer maps between endomaps, we can change the domain of those maps between endomaps to something bigger and get back the ones we were missing. (This is just a re-saying of what Arnaud said).

Comment: To be more precise, what you are looking for is this: Given any $S$-object $X$, you want an endomap $f_X : F_X \to F_X$ (where $F_X$ is some other $S$-object) so that if $\beta : Y \to Y$ is any endomap, then for every $g : X \to Y$ there is a unique F_g : f_X \to \beta$ (map of endomaps), and vice versa. (Look at maps out of the endomap $+1:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and how they relate to where you send $0$)

Comment: @DavidMyers I see... I had not understood Arnaud’s suggestion properly, as can be deduced from my previous comment. Thank you both for your help!