# Lawvere - Conceptual Mathematics - Monomorphisms in Category Endomaps

Tags: category-theory

**Problem:**

If $X^{\circlearrowleft \alpha}$ is any object of $S^\circlearrowleft$ for which there exists an *injective* $S^\circlearrowleft$-map $f$ to some $Y^{\circlearrowleft \beta}$ where $\beta$ is in the subcategory of *automorphisms*, then $\alpha$ itself must be injective.

The definition injectivity the book:

- A map $X \xrightarrow{a} Y$ is **injective** iff for any maps $T \xrightarrow{x_1} X$ and $T \xrightarrow{x2} X$ (in the same category) if $a \circ x_1=a \circ x_2$ then $x_1=x_2$.

The definition of $S^{\circlearrowleft}$ is: A category whose objects are sets equipped with endomaps.

I believe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821184/exercise-28-article-iii-schanuel-and-lawveres-conceptual-mathematics-2nd-e) claims that we need to show injectivity in the category of endomaps where they say:
`If x1 and x2 were not only S-maps, but also S↺-maps (for a given endomap τ on T), by the injectivity of f, we'd get x1=x2. However, this may not be the case.`
I don't know if that is right. My interpretation of the question is that we want to show $\alpha$ is injective in the category of sets because by definition $\alpha$ is simply a set map $\alpha\colon X \to X$. Is one interpretation more appropriate than the other?

Additionally, the hints in the other question seem like they want to invoke the universal property of the natural numbers (is this correct?), which is something the textbook won't even cover for another hundred pages or so.

Comment: I think you need to interpret $f$ as an injective $S$-map which is also an $S^\circlearrowleft$-map. The original post in the previous question then includes a complete proof: from $f\circ x_1=f\circ x_2$ we conclude $x_1=x_2$ as desired.

Comment: You've misinterpreted something in the old question-there can be no claim to be pricing $\alpha$ is injective as an endomap since $\alpha$ is simply not an map of endomaps.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Sorry, you're right, I got confused in my question: they are assuming they need $x_1,x_2: T \to X$ to be $S^\circlearrowleft$-maps, which I still think we don't need. Let me edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: I updated my question. Actually I'm not sure it's any clearer, but I quoted the line I am taking an issue with. I think you're right and we can conclude directly from $f \circ x_1 = f \circ x_2$, and that is how I originally intended to solve the problem, but the other question asker seems to disagree, as do the commenters.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Anyway, if at least one other person thinks it is reasonable to assume $f$ is an injective $S$-map AND $S^\circlearrowleft$ map, I'm willing to go with that (thanks for the sanity check) so feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To easily prove that an injective $S^\circlearrowleft$ map is also an injective $S$-map requires the Yoneda lemma or other tools more advanced than I believe the reader is expected to have at the given point in the book. So it's reasonable, especially since $f$ being injective in either category really is equivalent, to assume $f$ is injective as an $S$-map and proceed from there.